# multiple ajax request to the same ASP.NET Action at the same time

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have this Action in my asp.net mvc controller which receives an int parameter and returns some json dependent on it. this is how that action looks

```
Public JsonResult GetSomeData(int intParam)
{
    var someData = _someService.GetSomeDataByIntParam(intParam);
    return Json(someData);
}
```

So there is nothing special in here, all the work needed is done by instance of `SomeService` and then the action just returns the json. this part `_someService.GetSomeDataByIntParam(intParam);` takes from 35-80 milliseconds on average.
In front-end I have and Jquery code that makes Ajax call to this action and when it gets the answer it just puts the data from json somewhere in the DOM. this is the jquery code (including some `razor`)

```
@foreach (var intParam in Model.IntParams)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/SomeController/GetSomeData',
            data { intParam: @intParam }, 
            success : function (response) {
                var responseParam = response.param;
                if (response.anotherParam)
                    responseParam += '<span class="some-class">!</span>';

                var someForm1 = $('#some-from1-@intParam');
                someForm1.children('span.some-another-class').html(responseParam);

                var someForm2 = $('#some-from2-@intParam');
                someForm2.children('span.some-another-class').html(responseParam);
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

There will be on average 3-10 elements int `IntParams`. that js is executed immediately after the page is rendered. So whole scenario is like this. page is drawn the json data is queried and when its delivered back to js it is inserted somewhere in the DOM. the action which is returning json is queuing other request while it is executing one. so when those, suppose 5 ajax calls are made to the action only one gets executed at a time. (can this be made asynchronous without turning session state off ?) first request gets the answer in 30-80 milliseconds and the fifth gets the answer in 2-2.2 seconds. this is very crucial part in my application so I don't want to lose any milliseconds. I don't understand If the action takes on average 30-80 milliseconds why the fifth one gets the answer in 2 seconds. should not it be something like 400 (5 * 80) milliseconds ? or this call queuing is the thing that is taking too much time ? What can be done to make some optimizations. I image if there were more than 10 calls to execute it would take something like 5 seconds or so. So anyway what can be done to make this whole thing fast. Any suggestion would be appreciated. (even in js code)

Answer (score 1):

I think the model for the current view is having the issue.

Please correct me if this is your current scenario.
You have some kind of single array in `Model.IntParams` or it may be a list. 
for each Item in the `IntParams` you are sending requests to server.
Suppose if the count of items in 5 or 10, it will send 5, or 10 request and while development or testing it will be fine. Once you have the production data, it can be 100 or 1000s , then you need send that much request.
IIS will process each request by locking the session and we can't say this as a concurrent processing. Check this it may help you [jQuery Ajax - Running multiple requests against ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863510/jquery-ajax-running-multiple-requests-against-asp-net-mvc)

Also I will recommend you to have a strong model for the view,with all the properties you need to display. Once you have the strong model fill the data and pass to view.

View only responsible for how the data should display? You can set flags in model  , so that you just want to check that condition and decide what to do . Its also makes the code readable and easy to understood by another guy who work with you. I think you can improve your performance by modifying the model and mechanism which fills data to the model.

Comment: yeah I have just one collection of int in my model but the the view is actually a partial view that why i don't need other thing in my model. this partial view get injected in other view and other view get injected in layout so those other view have model that are specific to them

Comment: then make a specific view model for that view with all the required properties. I believe your current approach surely opens lot of issues in future. Also its a bad practice to send ajax request continuously in loop, which ultimately results the performance of the application. You can feel the difference only when you working with data.

Comment: I need to make ajax calls in loop I don't know what will the number of calls be so that's why I have it in loop what else can I do ? and all the parameters I require for that view are already in the model. I cant think of anything else to put in there except for that collection.

Comment: Why can't u form the model and fill the data.

Comment: you mean fill the model with data and then draw the view ? @VeeKayBee. If that's what you mean then the answer is simple. I don't want user to wait until those data is retrieved and just see browser loading. the page should be drawn an that data should be retrieved after that

Comment: @Dima you can have a separate view model for that particular partial view and pass the value and loads partial view